# VBA - Loop through x items in blocks of 100 x times

Tags: vba, loops

I've been struggling with this for a day now.
I have a list box that is populated with x items. Could be 1 - x

I need to take all the items in the list box and format them into a string
which I submit into an oracle database.  I'm using INLIST on the SQL side and because of that I can only have a maximum of 100 items in my string.

So for example if I was to have 547 items in the listbox, I would iterate through all 547 items, but at every 100 I would submit into the database, returning my result into my collection class, finishing with the last 47.

here's what i have so far.  There is some attempts to solve my problem in the code so if it's confusing i'll try to explain.

```
Public Function SearchBMS()
On Error GoTo HandleError

    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sESN As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim maxrec As Integer
    Dim itemcnt As Integer
    Dim iBlockCount As Integer

    With frmEngineCampaignSearch.lstbxESNNumbers
        itemcnt = .ListCount - 2
        'iBlockCount = GetBlockCount(itemcnt)
            x = 0
            maxrec = 100
            Debug.Assert itemcnt = 200

            For i = 0 To itemcnt
                For x = i To maxrec
                    MsgBox "test", vbOKOnly
                i = i + 100
                Next x
                    If i = itemcnt Then ' if I = last item than we put the closing parenthesis on our string
                        sESN = sESN & "'" & .list(i) & "'"
                    Else
                        sESN = sESN & "'" & .list(i) & "' , " ' otherwise there are more items so we seperate by comma
                    End If

                    If itemcnt <= 100 Then
                        Set rst = Nothing
                        'Set rst = rstGetCustomerInfo(sESN)
                        'LoadRSTToCollection rst
                    elseif

                    While x = maxrec
                        MsgBox "submit first 100", vbOKOnly
                        'Set rst = Nothing
                        'Set rst = rstGetCustomerInfo(sESN)
                        'LoadRSTToCollection rst
                        sESN = gC_sEMPTY_STRING
                        maxrec = maxrec + 100
                    Wend
                    x = x + 1

            Next i
    End With
HandleError:
If Err.Number > 0 Then
MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

End If
```

This function is to get the number of times I would have to perform the submission but i hit a road block on how to use it within the for loop

```
Public Function GetBlockCount(ByRef lItemCnt As Long) As Integer
Dim x As Double
If lItemCnt <= 100 Then
    GetBlockCount = 1
    Exit Function
ElseIf lItemCnt > 100 Then
    x = Round(lItemCnt / 100)
    If lItemCnt Mod 100 > 0 Then
        x = x + 1
    Else
    GetBlockCount = x
    Exit Function
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it may help you: in Oracle, you can do multiple INs to get around the 100 element limit.  For example: `x in (....) or x in (....) or x in (...)`.

Comment: Can't you divide your count by 100 and determine if the result is an integer?  It will only be an integer when your count is 100, 200, 300, etc...  Then process the code if the result is an integer, otherwise continue appending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to clean it out and make it more readable. Then look at it and the solution will be much clearer.

Here is a simple skeleton of what it should look like:

```
I = 100
Txt = Get100Requests(I)
Do While Txt <> ""
  'use txt
  I = I + 100
  Txt = Get100Requests(I)
Loop

Function Get100Requests(FromItem As Integer) As String
  If FromItem => frmEngineCampaignSearch.lstbxESNNumbers.ListCount Then Exit Function
  Dim I As Integer
  I + FromItem
  Do While I < FromItem + 99 And I < frmEngineCampaignSearch.lstbxESNNumbers.ListCount
    Get100Requests = Get100Requests & "'" & frmEngineCampaignSearch.lstbxESNNumbers.list(i) & "', " 
    I = I + 1
  Loop
  Get100Requests = Left(Get100Requests, Len(Get100Requests)-2)
Exit Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I see the angle you're taking and with a little tweaking this will work perfectly.  Much obliged.